# jquery show button if all selectboxes are selected

Tags: jquery, select, hide, show

```
$("select").bind("change", function(event) {
    if ("" != $("option:selected", this).val() && "" != $("option:selected", $("select")).val()) {
        $("#submit").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#submit").hide();          
    }
});
```

I have seven selectboxes and a submit button in a form. I want to show submit button only all of selectboxes are selected (some of them have default option with no value, button should be active only if selected options contain value). Was using this code but it didnt work after i start to get four of selectboxes from another php file with ajax.

How can i revise this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use length property with selector returning `selected` select with selected value *not* equal to `empty` string.

```
$("select").bind("change", function(event) {
    if($("select:selected[value!='']").length == $("select").length)
         $("#submit").fadeIn();
    else 
         $("#submit").hide(); 
});
```

I would suggest you to use some `class` with select to be specific.

```
$(".select-class").bind("change", function(event) {
    if($(".select:selected[value!='']").length == $(".select").length)
         $("#submit").fadeIn();
    else 
         $("#submit").hide(); 
});
```

Comment: What about default empty values?

Comment: Attribute selector would check for value like [value!=''], updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("select").bind("change", function(event) {
    if($("select:selected[value!='']").length == $("select").length)
         $("#submit").fadeIn();
    else 
         $("#submit").hide(); 
});
```